# Sorting case insensitively in QAbstractItemModel

Tags: python, sorting, pyqt4, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I have trouble with trying create my own sorting function with QAbstractItemModel. It works but not case insensitive. I have tried to use QSortFilterProxyModel, but any success. My sort function:

```
def sort(self, col, order):
    self.emit(SIGNAL("layoutAboutToBeChanged()"))
    self.tableData = sorted(self.tableData, key=operator.itemgetter(col))       
    if order == Qt.AscendingOrder:
        self.tableData.reverse()
    self.emit(SIGNAL("layoutChanged()"))
```

I am using QTableView. How I could make it case insensitive?

Full example:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import operator
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        header = ["one", "two"]
        tableDict = [["abcdef", "tuvwx"], ["aBcde", "TUvWx"], ["acdef","tUvWX"], ["Acdef", "TUVwx"], ["ACdef", "TUVwx"]]
        self.myTable = newTableModel(header, tableDict)

        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.myTable.tableView)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test table")

class newTableModel(QAbstractTableModel): 
    def __init__(self, header, data, parent=None, *args):
        super(newTableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tableView = QTableView()
        self.tableData = data
        self.header = header

        self.tableView.setShowGrid(True)
        self.tableView.setFrameStyle( QFrame.NoFrame )
        self.tableView.setFocusPolicy( Qt.NoFocus )
        self.tableView.setSelectionMode( QAbstractItemView.NoSelection )

        vHeader = self.tableView.verticalHeader()
        vHeader.setVisible(False)
        vHeader.setStretchLastSection(False)
        hHeader = self.tableView.horizontalHeader()
        hHeader.setVisible(True)
        hHeader.setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.tableView.setModel(self)
        self.tableView.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
        vHeader.setResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        self.tableView.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.tableView.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    def rowCount(self, parent): 
        return len(self.tableData) 

    def columnCount(self, parent): 
        return len(self.tableData[0]) 

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return "{0}".format(self.tableData[row][col])
        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if index.isValid():
             return True
        return False

    def flags(self, index):
        fl = QAbstractTableModel.flags(self, index)
        if index.column() == 0:
            fl |= Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable
        return fl

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.header[col]

    def sort(self, col, order):
        self.emit(SIGNAL("layoutAboutToBeChanged()"))
        self.tableData = sorted(self.tableData, key=operator.itemgetter(col))      
        if order == Qt.AscendingOrder:
            self.tableData.reverse()
        self.emit(SIGNAL("layoutChanged()"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This table data in example shows sorting - non case sensitive.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have updated code, now with full example

Comment: use `self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(0, 0), self.index(self.rowCount()-1, self.columnCount()-1))` 
at the end of the function, also change `def rowCount(self, parent)` to `def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex())` and  `def columnCount(self, parent)` to `def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex())`

Comment: I have to do something another wrong, cause still not works. E.g. in first column where I have strings, lot of names, first of all big letters are sorted and then lower. I would like to have sorting Aa, Bb,... and not ABC..abc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to convert the values to lower (or upper) case in the sort-key that is passed to the `sorted` function. For improved efficiency, you can also use the *reverse* argument to avoid doing that in a separate step:

```
def sort(self, col, order):
    self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
    self.tableData = sorted(
        self.tableData,
        key=lambda row: row[col].lower(),
        reverse=(order != Qt.AscendingOrder),
        )
    self.layoutChanged.emit()
```

Note that `sorted` does a *stable sort*, so equal values (after the key has been applied), will keep their original places. Thus, the second column in your example won't show any changes when it's sorted, since the values are all the "same" (if you ignore case).

**UPDATE**:

Here's a solution that will work for strings and numbers. It assumes the columns aren't a mixture of the two types:

```
def sort(self, col, order):
    if self.tableData and self.tableData[0]:
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        if isinstance(self.tableData[0][col], str):
            sortkey = lambda row: row[col].lower()
        else:
            sortkey = operator.itemgetter(col)
        self.tableData = sorted(
            self.tableData, key=sortkey,
            reverse=(order != Qt.AscendingOrder))
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining anf help! How to check if data are not str type? Cause this solution not working for multi type table which I have (numbers and strings, depends column). `lower()` not possible use for int or float. But it works cool about strings!

Comment: @Dave. You can just do `str(row[col]).lower()`.

Comment: I tried it before but that is bad about sorting then (e.g. 11, 115, 178, 25, 278,...)

Comment: @Dave. So the columns are actually all strings or all numbers, rather than a mixture?

Comment: yes, separetely in columns. Some are `str` only and some columns are `int` or `float`. I was looking for some way to check type - then I could use specific `sorted()` method for every situation